# Smooth scrolling with sticky div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a sticky div as smooth as in this example: http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2010/11/13/weekinreview/deficits-graphic.html?src=tp&_r=0

Right now, my example isnt smooth at all, but really jumpy. I have this JS-code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

        var scroll_top = $(this).scrollTop();
           if (scroll_top > 66) {//height of header
             $('.wrapper').addClass('sticky');
          } else {
          $('.wrapper').removeClass('sticky');
          }
   });
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <h4>Ausgaben in Millionen Franken</h4>
     <div class="background">
          <div id="kunstmuseum"></div><div id="historisch"></div><div id="naturhist"></div><div id="kulturen"></div><div id="antik"></div><div id="beyeler"></div><div id="weitereMuseen"></div><div id="theaterBasel"></div><div id="kaserne"></div><div id="weitereTheater"></div><div id="sinfonie"></div><div id="jazz"></div><div id="rock"></div><div id="literatur"></div><div id="erbe"></div><div id="wettbewerb"></div><div id="weiteres"></div><div id="zoo"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="eins">0</div>
    <div id="zwei">30</div>
    <div id="drei">60</div>
    <div id="vier">90</div>
    <div id="fuenf">120</div>
    <div id="eingespart"><h4>Total eingespart:&ensp;<div id="totalSum">0&ensp;CHF</div></h4></div>
</div>
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w640ftLf/3/

Comment: Example is not smooth when I use my scroll wheel. They seem to update the divs top position using Javascript instead of give it an absolute position. The start of your approach is better than the example :)

Comment: may want to look at bootstrap affix: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really how I would do it, but your function works fine.

The easiest way to fix your problem is to add `padding-top: 66px;` (66 being the header height) to the body element at the same time you add the class 'sticky'.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I added the line like this: $(window).scroll(function () {

            var scroll_top = $(this).scrollTop();
               if (scroll_top > 66) {//height of header
                 $('.wrapper').addClass('sticky');
                 document.body.style.paddingTop == "66px";
              } else {
              $('.wrapper').removeClass('sticky');
              }
       });

Comment: but I still have the annoying flickering when I scroll using the scrollbars (slowly moving the scrollbars down)

Comment: If you provide a new (and slightly better) example I'll fix it for you.

Comment: The JS fiddle example is not very clear to me. The HTML markup does not seem right to me. Also I'm not sure which element is supposed to be sticky.

Comment: ok, sorry for that. I cleaned the example up and updated the link. What should stick is the div with the class "wrapper"

Comment: I created a new JSFiddle example on http://jsfiddle.net/ezdd1u3f/3/ . I changed quite a bit because your example turned out to be a little bit different then I expected.

Comment: I created a new JSFiddle example on http://jsfiddle.net/ezdd1u3f/3/ . I changed quite a bit because your example turned out to be a little bit different then I expected.

FYI, this only works if your page is actually long enough when it loads. Since your page isn't very long you'll probably need to adjust the window width and then refresh the example again.

Comment: thanks, it works in chrome, but doesn't work in firefox

Comment: I made a small error. The new example http://jsfiddle.net/ezdd1u3f/4/ also works in Firefox.

Comment: And again I made an error (forgot a semicolon), which is adjusted in http://jsfiddle.net/ezdd1u3f/5

Comment: Can I reset the offset value on page resize?

Comment: Sure, I added a couple lines of code at the bottom: http://jsfiddle.net/ezdd1u3f/6/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66522/discussion-between-felix-and-eric-osw).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're attaching the `sticky` class to the wrong element. Try this, instead:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scroll_top = $(document).scrollTop();
    if (scroll_top > 66) {//height of header
        $('.background').addClass('sticky');
     } else {
        $('.background').removeClass('sticky');
     }
});
```

Also, for education, you can take a look at [how your example is doing it](http://graphics8.nytimes.com/packages/js/newsgraphics/2010/1113-deficit-tables/stickyDiv.js).

Comment: thanks, but I need all the content so <h4> content and also divs below the background tag. So I think a wrapper is the right idea. Unfortunately, I dont fully understand the example code, but thank you for posting.